# jQuery each combined with replaceWith issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, each, replacewith

I am trying to loop through each element with a class and then wrap it with a div, and then continue to the next one.

Currently using this...

```
$('.img-editable').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "IMG") {
        $(this).replaceWith('<span class="img-edit-container">'+this.outerHTML+'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button></span>');
    } else {
        $(this).replaceWith('<span class="img-edit-container bg-img-edit-container">'+this.outerHTML+'<button class="btn btn-default bg-img-edit img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button></span>');
    }
});
```

It works in simple cases. But the challenge is when there is nested elements like this...

```
    <div class="img-editable>
        <div id="something else">
            <div class="img-editable"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then it falls apart and the inner element doesn't get wrapped correctly.

My belief is the `each()` function is looping the outermost elements and when it matches the first one then it performs the `replaceWith()` and then continues. But by the time the loop gets to the next one (inner), the reference to second inner element that matches is no longer there (according to the browser).

I also tried this...

```
var setupImgWrapper = function(elem) {
    if (elem.prop("tagName") == "IMG") {
        elem.replaceWith('<span class="img-edit-container">'+this.outerHTML+'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button></span>');
        elem.children('.img-edtiable').each(function(i) {
            setupImgWrapper($(this));
        });
    } else {
        elem.replaceWith('<span class="img-edit-container bg-img-edit-container">'+this.outerHTML+'<button class="btn btn-default bg-img-edit img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button></span>');
        elem.children('.img-edtiable').each(function(i) {
            setupImgWrapper($(this));
        });
    }
}

$('.img-editable').each(function(i) {
    setupImgWrapper($(this));
});
```

This completely failed.

I would love to know how we can overcome this? Is there a way to maintain the DOM reference after `replaceWith()` is performed, or can we update it?

**TL;DR** After performing `replaceWith` in loop on selected elements, descendant element references seem to break and these elements aren't updated successfully.

Thanks!

---

## Solution As Accepted Below

```
$('.img-editable').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "IMG") {
        $(this).wrap('<span class="img-edit-container"></span>');
        $(this).after('<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button>');
    } else {
        $(this).wrap('<span class="img-edit-container bg-img-edit-container"></span>');
        $(this).after('<button class="btn btn-default bg-img-edit img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method provided by jQuery that does exactly what you need.

### Here's a demo

```js
$('body > div').each(function() {
  $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Normal Element</div>

<div>
  <span>Simple inline element</span>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h1>More Stuff</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `.img-editable > ... > .img-editable` breaks your code, you should prefer a better selector that fit your needs. I can assist you with that, just post a comment to this answer and we'll figure something out. :)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it worked for me and was the first response. Although it looks like `wrapAll` may actually be even faster. I will update my question with full solution. Thank you for your fast help!

Comment: [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) creates **one wrapper for all** selected elements, while [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) creates **one wrapper for every element**. Depends on what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [wrapall](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) api along with `each`

```
$( ".img-editable" ).wrapAll( "<span class='img-edit-container'/>");

$(".img-edit-container .img-editable").each( function(){
  if ( $( this ).prop("tagName") == "IMG" )
  {
    $(this).parent().append ( '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button>' );
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).parent().append ( '<button class="btn btn-default bg-img-edit img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button>' );
  }
});
```

or even simpler

```
$( ".img-editable" ).wrapAll( "<span class='img-edit-container'/>");

$(".img-edit-container").append( '<button class="btn btn-default bg-img-edit img-edit popover-trigger"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></button>' );

$(".img-edit-container img.img-editable").siblings( "button" ).toggleClass( "btn-sm" ).toggleClass( "bg-img-edit" );
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a fast way to achieve this, and I could possibly even skip the .each I think with some work. I'm accepting the first answer though as it also worked. But I think this is a smart approach! Thank you for sharing

Comment: You beat me to it... Knew it was possible to skip the .each altogether! Thank you